# Google map place autocomplete in iOS

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ios7, autocomplete

I am using Google map place integration. i am new in Google map API. I am Trying to implement autocomplete for google place. I have gone through Google place autocomplete API
But i can't. can any one help me to integrate autocomplete for google map.I used one git hub sample code from this link[enter link description here](https://github.com/spoletto/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete)

this project Google map used , but i want to used google map . when i am changing apple map as a MKMapView to GMSMapView .`

```
@class SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery;

@interface SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> {
    NSArray *searchResultPlaces;
    SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteQuery *searchQuery;
    MKPointAnnotation *selectedPlaceAnnotation;

    BOOL shouldBeginEditing;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;

@end
```

then it not running. it giving error  **'GMSMapView' may not respond to 'setRegion:animated:' when i am removing annotation**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (![searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        // User tapped the 'clear' button.
        shouldBeginEditing = NO;
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:selectedPlaceAnnotation];
 }
}
```

please tell me any way/tutorial/stapes so i can do autocomplete with google place.

Comment: plz explane dawn vote for this question

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but please try to show some example code, and a clear explanation of the problems (including errors) that you are experiencing.

Comment: i need google places autocomplete api integration with iOS

Comment: i need to know the stapes involved in google places autocomplete api integration with ios7.

Answer (score 0):

With the very simple three steps you can integrate such functionality using [MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField](https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/MVAutocompletePlaceSearchTextField)

[image]

Comment: How wil i get lat and long from the search address/

Comment: Either use Geocoding if you do manually or in my Control you can check delegate method  `placeSearchResponseForSelectedPlace:` in which you will find every detail of that location -  `responseDict[@"result"][@"geometry"][@"location"]`